# How to pass class by Interface to AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, inheritance, mobile, android-asynctask

I've got a little architectural problem.

I've created an abstract Activity class named BaseActivity.java
In this activity I put my business logic login call etc.

This is the basic BaseActivity code:

```
abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BaseActivityInterface {

      protected ApiParameters apiParameters;
      private BaseActivityInterface calledActivity;

      protected void getLoggedUser(BaseActivityInterface calledActivity) {
                this.calledActivity = calledActivity;
                GetLoggedUserTask getLoggedUserTask = new GetLoggedUserTask(this.apiParameters, BaseActivity.this);
                getLoggedUserTask.execute(Utility.LOGIN_URL);
      }

      @Override
      public void updateActivity(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {
          if (response.getInt("status") == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
              this.initUserObject(response);
              if (this.calledActivity != null) {
                  this.calledActivity.updateActivity(response);
              }
          } else {
              Toast.makeText(this, response.getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
              this.startActivity(intent);
              finish();
          }
     }
}
```

this is the AsyncTask called GetLoggedUserTask:

```
public class GetLoggedUserTask extends  AsyncTask<String, BaseActivityInterface, String> {
    private ApiParameters apiParameters;
    private BaseActivityInterface response;

    public GetLoggedUserTask(ApiParameters apiParameters, BaseActivityInterface response) {
        this.apiParameters = apiParameters;
        this.response = response;
    }
```

this is my child class of BaseActivity called CustomerActivity

```
public class CustomersActivity extends BaseActivity implements BaseActivityInterface {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.getLoggedUser(CustomersActivity.this);
    }


    @Override
    public void updateActivity(JSONObject loginResult) throws JSONException {
        .....
    }
}
```

and finally my interface BaseActivityInterface

```
public interface BaseActivityInterface extends Serializable {
    void updateActivity(JSONObject loginResult) throws JSONException;
}
```

the flow should be: start CustomerActivity.java, pass on super to do a getLoggetUser() and from super BaseActivity, start an AsyncTask. This is the hot point:

when I pass in the asyncTask construct the "BaseActivity.this", and I do debug, the reference of "response" element into GetLoggedUserTask is referred to child CustomerActivity:

[Class reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPtY6.png)

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong. `BaseActivity` is an `abstract` class which means it can not be instantiated. `BaseActivity.this` will return you the instance of a concrete class that extends `BaseActivity`, in this case `CustomersActivity`. You will never see `BaseActivity.this` as an instance because it's not possible in java, to have instances of abstract classes.